# How to create a text file containing filenames in subdirectories of a directory, and prepend a parent directory name to each row?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, awk

I have a folder named "1" containing the following:

```
folder "1"
    folder "a1"
        file "1.txt"    
        file "2.txt"
    folder "b2"
        file "3.txt"
        file "4.txt"
        file "5.txt"
    folder "c3"
        file "6.txt"
        file "7.txt"
        file "8.txt"
        file "9.txt"
    file "1.txt" – just skip it, don't take it into account!
    file "2.txt" – just skip it, don't take it into account!
```

I want to collect filenames inside of all subdirectories and prepend each row with its parent directory name followed by `":"` char. Note: directory "1" may contain files, I need to skip them. Their names are not to be included in **result.txt**!

So, I want to get

**result.txt**:

```
    a1:1.txt    
    a1:2.txt
    b2:3.txt
    b2:4.txt
    b2:5.txt
    c3:6.txt
    c3:7.txt
    c3:8.txt
    c3:9.txt
```

Is it possible? All I've found is `find` command, but I can't imagine how to apply it to this problem... Note: I'm using Cygwin, or busybox under windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find -exec`:

```
cd 1
find . -mindepth 2 -name "*.txt" -exec bash -c 'f="${1#./}"; echo "${f/\//:}"' - '{}' \;
a1:1.txt
a1:2.txt
b2:3.txt
b2:4.txt
b2:5.txt
c3:6.txt
c3:7.txt
c3:8.txt
c3:9.txt
```

`-mindepth 2` will make sure to not to match files directly under `1` directory.

Comment: Wow. Can you explain the stuff that follows `bash -c`?

Comment: `bash -c` just executes a command line containing 1 or more bash commands.

Comment: I don't see... where is the name of the output file ("result.txt")?

Comment: @anubhava: with this answer, I see the output in the console. But I want to write the result directly to a file...

Comment: To redirect output you can use standard redirection: **`find . -mindepth 2 -name "*.txt" -exec bash -c 'f="${1#./}"; echo "${f/\//:}"' - '{}' \; > results.out`**